# Launching selemium scripts from browser for screen capture

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, screen-capture

I am looking for creating a functional training package for a web based product (more like a screen capture).
However, the requirement is not just to have screen capture, but to have a test mode for the training where we can prompt the user to click on the screen and check if they have done proper flow.

for e.g. A banker will first go through the screen capture to see "how to open an account" in the core banking application . Later user will be presented with a test where user has to click through all the controls and flow.

I have seen selenium being used for authoring good UI automation test cases, so I wanted to explore the possibility of using selenium for creating these training modules

These training modules needs to be launched from intranet application. Is it possible to launch selenium authored UI automation test cases from the browser? I want to stay away from writing any extensions or plugins.

I haven't used selenium and I might be completely off tangent here, so any other suggestion to achieve this using open source tools are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing any scripts, you may consider downloading Selenium IDE. It has a recording and replay function that may meet your need.

For a fast tutorial, please follow this link. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsHyDIyA3dg

Hope it helps.